# How to send destination parameter in URL when redirecting user if not logged in?

Tags: authentication, redirect, parameters, localhost

I'm making a redirection on the login required pages.

If user is not logged in and he/she tried to open the login required page directly then he or she will be redirected to the login page with a destination parameter
Like this:-

```
https://localhost/example-app/login?destination=login-required-page
```

And when it will redirect to login page then there will be check of destination at the top of the file

//LOGIN CHECK
`login_required_page.php` :-

```
if(empty($user_id)) {
    redirect(BASE_URL . '/login? destination=' . $page_section);
    //page section is the page type ex. Login, signup, settings
}
```

Here is config file that contains the redirect function:-

```
function redirect($destination) {
    header("Location: " . $destination);
}
```

Here is the login page redirection block :-

```
if($_GET['destination'])) {
     $destination = $_GET['destination'];
     redirect(BASE_URL . '/' . $destination);
     //Only for checking I don't added redirection button onclick
     //Added redirection at top of the page so that I can check it's working fine or not
}
```

And the error is coming on the login page.that localhost redirected you so many times and page is not able to open!

Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: So where in this are you performing the actual login?

Comment: When I open login required page URL directly without login, then the login required page will redirect it to the login page with destination parameter and the value of the destination parameter will be the name of the login required page in URL then login page willl check for parameter and if it is there then login page will redirect to the destination page that was mentioned in the destination parameter but the issue is that when login required page redirects to login page then localhost says localhost redirected you so many times (the issue mentioned is on login page)

Comment: I meant, where are you actually checking the credentials the user submitted? You say, _"Here is the login page"_, but the only code you have shown there, is the one that redirects elsewhere again.

Comment: The page where I check user credentials is the login page

Comment: And when user will be clicking on login the credentials will be checked and if there is destination parameter in the url then it will redirect to the destination page after successful login if there is no parameter then it will redirect to the home page as usually after successful login (**The redirection will happen only after successful login**)